# How to dynamically calculate a field value of current log entry from its preceding log entry? Or should this be done at kibana visualization side?

Tags: logstash, kibana

My csv data format:

```
Date   Total
-----  ---
date1, 10
date2, 15
date2, 30
```

I want logstash to get the dates in the timestamp field, "Total" in total field (its easy upto this part) but I also want to calculate the "Increment" field by diffing the "Totals" from the previous log/csv entry. So the output is somewhat like this

```
Date   Total Increment
-----  ---   ---------
date1, 10,   0
date2, 15,   5
date2, 30,   15
```

Also, if I want to visualise the time difference between different log entries, how do I do that?
Any tips would be highly appcreciated.

Answer (score 0):

logstash doesn't provide much in terms of correlation between events.

Take a look at the elapsed{} filter, which keeps a cache of "start" events in order to tag the "end" events when they arrive.  You could use a system like that in your own filter to compute the running total.

If you just want the current total, you can aggregate and display the sum in kibana.